# SuiteScript - Create a popup link on a Purchase Order Line

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm looking for a method to create a "popup" window link at transaction line level to display a list of sub-records, almost identical in nature to the Inventory Detail popup, but it would be a custom suitelet form.

So, basically I want to have a clickable line in VIEW and EDIT modes, where the user clicks on a hyperlink which will open a popup and display a list of ASN subrecords linked to the specific Purchase Order line.

There is a 1-many relationship between each PO line and ASN records.

I would envisage the "link" for each line would be a counter of the number of linked subrecords, and if zero, the link would be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a Suitelet that you call from its deployment.
2. Make a sublist field on the record type you're looking to put the popup link on.
3. Make a client script that is pointing to the record type you're looking to put the popup link on. In this script, hook into the line level sublist, and use something like `<href>` and/or `<a>` HTML tags to format the link in the sublist field you made in step two. You'll want to create the popup by specifying relevant parameters in [window.open(parameters)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)